# How does dalvik findlibrary?

Tags: android, dalvik

first, in System.java, it calls Runtime to loadLibrary.

```
public static void loadLibrary(String libName) {
    SecurityManager smngr = System.getSecurityManager();
    if (smngr != null) {
        smngr.checkLink(libName);
    }
    Runtime.getRuntime().loadLibrary(libName, VMStack.getCallingClassLoader());
}
```

second, it calles VMStack.getCallingClassLoader() to findLibrary.

```
void loadLibrary(String libraryName, ClassLoader loader) {
    if (loader != null) {
        String filename = loader.findLibrary(libraryName);
        if (filename == null) {
            throw new UnsatisfiedLinkError("Couldn't load " + libraryName + ": " +
                    "findLibrary returned null");
        }
        //....
    }
}
```

So, i think `VMStack.getCallingClassLoader()` is the most meaningful. 
But in its jni file **dalvik_system_VMStack.cpp**, the `Dalvik_dalvik_system_VMStack_getCallingClassLoader` function is hard to learn. And at last, how dalvik findLibrary?

```
static void Dalvik_dalvik_system_VMStack_getCallingClassLoader(const u4* args,
    JValue* pResult){
    ClassObject* clazz =
        dvmGetCaller2Class(dvmThreadSelf()->interpSave.curFrame);

    UNUSED_PARAMETER(args);

    if (clazz == NULL)
        RETURN_PTR(NULL);
    RETURN_PTR(clazz->classLoader);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

`VMStack.getCallingClassLoader()` returns the class loader of the class that declared the method that called the current method.  In other words, if my function `foo()` called `Runtime.loadLibrary()`, it would return `foo`'s class loader.

The point of all that is to make sure the library is loaded in the context of whoever called `findLibrary`, rather than in the context of `java.lang.Runtime`.

There's a good chance `findLibrary()` is implemented by `BaseDexClassLoader`, which calls into `DexPathList.findLibrary()`, which does the actual work.  The interesting bit there is the walk through `nativeLibraryDirectories`, which is initialized from the `libraryPath` argument to the `BaseDexClassLoader` constructor (which gets it from `PathClassLoader` or `DexClassLoader`).

For Android apps, take a look at `android.app.ApplicationLoaders`, which uses a `PathClassLoader`.  If you trace that back far enough you'll see the directory being retrieved from `ApplicationInfo.nativeLibraryDir`.

**EDIT:** going deeper to address comment...

`/system/lib` comes from the `java.library.path` property, which the core libraries extract from the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.  The app-specific library dir is configured by the framework.

The `PackageManagerService` constructor sets the lib path in `mAppLibInstallDir`, and `setInternalAppNativeLibraryPath()` configures `nativeLibraryDir`.

`DexPathList.splitLibraryPath()` combines the `java.library.path` path with the APK-specific path.  See the comments there for notes on ordering.

Comment: But where is the realization? Why android find so in system/lib and apk's lib dir?